# How to call a method from a separate class java

Tags: java, class, methods

I'm trying to call a method from a separate class in java but it doesn't seem to work, or I'm doing something wrong. What I want to achieve is to call my `Race` method which is in the `RacingEvent` class to my main program (Check the comment in the main program).

Here is the class:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RacingEvent {
    private SimpleWindow w;
    private RaceTrack track;
    private Turtle t1 = new Turtle(w, 200, 400);
    private Turtle t2 = new Turtle(w, 300, 400);

    public RacingEvent(RaceTrack track, Turtle t1, Turtle t2) {
        this.t1 = t1;
        this.t2 = t2;
        this.track = track;
 }

    public void Race() {
        t1.penDown();
        t2.penDown();
        Random rand = new Random();

        Turtle t1 = new Turtle(w, 200, 400);
        Turtle t2 = new Turtle(w, 300, 400);

        while (t1.getY() > track.getyFinish() && t2.getY() > track.getyFinish()) {
            int turtle1 = rand.nextInt(3);
            int turtle2 = rand.nextInt(3);
            t1.forward(turtle1);
            t2.forward(turtle2);

            SimpleWindow.delay(10);
        }


        int diff1 = t1.getY() - track.getyFinish();
        int diff2 = t2.getY() - track.getyFinish();

        SimpleWindow w = new SimpleWindow(200, 100, "Winner");

        if (t1.getY() <= track.getyFinish()) {
            w.moveTo(20, 40);
            w.writeText("T1 won with a " + diff2 + " step(s) lead!");
        } else if (t2.getY() <= track.getyFinish()) {
            w.moveTo(20, 40);
            w.writeText("T2 won with a " + diff1 + " step(s) lead!");
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the main program where I need to call the method:

```
public class TurtleRace {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleWindow w = new SimpleWindow(600, 600, "TurtleRace");
        int yStart = 400; 
        int yFinish = 100; 

        RaceTrack track = new RaceTrack(w, yStart, yFinish);
        ColorTurtle t1 = new ColorTurtle(w, 250, yStart, java.awt.Color.RED);
        ColorTurtle t2 = new ColorTurtle(w, 350, yStart, java.awt.Color.BLUE);

        track.draw(w);
        w.waitForMouseClick();

        RacingEvent event = new RacingEvent(track, t1, t2);
        /*Call Race Method*/
    }
}
```

Comment: What didn't seem to work? Show use what you tried?

Comment: You can't call `event.Race();` ?

Comment: Tried it but then I get an java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @Rob where do you get NPE ??

Comment: What is the call stack of the NPE?

Comment: RacingEvent.java:31
TurtleRace.java:22

Comment: @Rob but what is line 31 in your code ??

Comment: I see you redefining `t1` and `t2` in `Race()` method. Did you by any chance got that wrong?

Comment: t1.forward(turtle1); @31 RacingEvent

event.Race(); @ 22 TurtleRace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this

```
RacingEvent event = new RacingEvent(track, t1, t2);
```

You are just creating and instantiating an object of the RacingEvent class.

The function call is yet to be made.

You should write this to call the function.

```
event.Race();
```

Hope it solves the problem.

Comment: Did some minor modifications to my RacingEvent class but then I got it working. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Cool thing is that the accepted answer does not solve the problem :D

Answer (score 2):

`RacingEvent` does not initialize its `w` field. You might want to pass the value that is available to the caller (called `w` there, too) to the constructor and set `w` to the argument passed in.

In detail:

Change the constructor to

```
public RacingEvent(SimpleWindow w, RaceTrack track, Turtle t1, Turtle t2) {
        this.w = w;
        this.t1 = t1;
        this.t2 = t2;
        this.track = track;
 }
```

and call it like this:

```
 RacingEvent event = new RacingEvent(w, track, t1, t2);
 event.race();
```

Comment: +1 Oh you are correct. It's being used at `   Turtle t1 = new Turtle(w, 200, 400);` before initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified solution:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;

class SimpleWindow {
  public SimpleWindow(int i, int i1, String winner) {
    //To change body of created methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
  }

  public static void delay(int i) {
    //To change body of created methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
  }

  public void moveTo(int i, int i1) {
    //To change body of created methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
  }

  public void writeText(String s) {
    //To change body of created methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
  }

  public void waitForMouseClick() {
    //To change body of created methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
  }
}
class ColorTurtle extends Turtle {
  public ColorTurtle(SimpleWindow w, int i, int yStart, Color red) {
    //To change body of created methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
  }

  public ColorTurtle(SimpleWindow w, int i, int i1) {
    super(w, i, i1);
  }
}

class RaceTrack {
  private int yFinish;

  public RaceTrack(SimpleWindow w, int yStart, int yFinish) {
    //To change body of created methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
  }

  public int getyFinish() {
    return yFinish;
  }

  public void draw(SimpleWindow w) {
    //To change body of created methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
  }
}
class Turtle {
  private int y;

  public Turtle(SimpleWindow w, int i, int i1) {
    //To change body of created methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
  }

  Turtle() {
  }

  public void penDown() {
    //To change body of created methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
  }

  public int getY() {
    return y;
  }

  public void forward(int turtle1) {
    //To change body of created methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
  }
}
class RacingEvent {
  private SimpleWindow w;
  private RaceTrack track;
  private Turtle t1 = new Turtle(w, 200, 400);
  private Turtle t2 = new Turtle(w, 300, 400);

  public RacingEvent(RaceTrack track, Turtle t1, Turtle t2) {
    this.t1 = t1;
    this.t2 = t2;
    this.track = track;
  }

  public void Race() {
    t1.penDown();
    t2.penDown();
    Random rand = new Random();

    Turtle t1 = new Turtle(w, 200, 400);
    Turtle t2 = new Turtle(w, 300, 400);

    while (t1.getY() > track.getyFinish() && t2.getY() > track.getyFinish()) {
      int turtle1 = rand.nextInt(3);
      int turtle2 = rand.nextInt(3);
      t1.forward(turtle1);
      t2.forward(turtle2);

      SimpleWindow.delay(10);
    }


    int diff1 = t1.getY() - track.getyFinish();
    int diff2 = t2.getY() - track.getyFinish();

    SimpleWindow w = new SimpleWindow(200, 100, "Winner");

    if (t1.getY() <= track.getyFinish()) {
      w.moveTo(20, 40);
      w.writeText("T1 won with a " + diff2 + " step(s) lead!");
    } else if (t2.getY() <= track.getyFinish()) {
      w.moveTo(20, 40);
      w.writeText("T2 won with a " + diff1 + " step(s) lead!");
    }
  }
}
public class TurtleRace {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleWindow w = new SimpleWindow(600, 600, "TurtleRace");
    int yStart = 400;
    int yFinish = 100;

    RaceTrack track = new RaceTrack(w, yStart, yFinish);
    ColorTurtle t1 = new ColorTurtle(w, 250, yStart, java.awt.Color.RED);
    ColorTurtle t2 = new ColorTurtle(w, 350, yStart, java.awt.Color.BLUE);

    track.draw(w);
    w.waitForMouseClick();

    RacingEvent event = new RacingEvent(track, t1, t2);
    /*Call Race Method*/
    event.Race();
  }
}
```